# Can China discriminate all Western companies involved in critical technologies now that the U.S. banned critical technologies to China?

Tags: china, international-law, wto

YMTC recently acquired semiconductor manufacturing equipment from Western companies with the intention of utilizing them in their factory and receiving ongoing maintenance and support. The tools' depreciation is spread out over numerous years. However, the retrospective imposition of controls by the West on maintenance and support has greatly diminished their worth to YMTC, potentially rendering them worthless altogether.

So my question is if China would be justified to not grant contract to foreign companies due to the fact the U.S. may once again ban critical equipment. It seems only natural that China would want to be 100% independent from now on and give preferential contracts to Chinese companies in these critical sectors.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what China would be "justified to do" is a question that depends entirely on personal opinion.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly. Say bye-bye to like 80% of electronics manufacturing, especially after they invade and conquer Taiwan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the US is attempting to do is slow down the convergence of Chinese technological capability with that of the West, as well as rebuild Western supply chains that are crucial for military capacity.

Whilst the economic value of existing machinery may be diminished in the hands of private industry, if sanctions mean it can no longer be properly maintained, that doesn't mean the machines have been made worthless to the Chinese state.

If the machines they have embody advanced technology and techniques, then simple possession is likely to be valuable for their own R&D purposes, even if the machines can't be used for manufacturing.

Therefore, if there are things which China can currently continue to buy but which may later be sanctioned, I see no reason why they would stop buying in the meantime. The state will de-risk private purchases by simply providing private industry with the purchase capital and sanctions insurance.

Answer (score 0):

The question sounds like "should China ban its companies from buying the worthless equipment". Normally a sane company either would not be doing or may also take risks expecting that equipment somehow will not be worthless. Maybe they just want to reverse engineer them.

But in some cases there may be regulations preventing company managers from taking very risky decisions, even if this is more often in banking industry. There are also many technical regulations to protect the safety of the clients.

Lots of enforced precautions may make business inefficient so China must think if it makes sense.